# sequelize users.findOne using two parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to use `users.findOne` method **using two params** like in the example below, not just with the `id` or `name` but with both

```
 const user = await Tags.findOne({
    where: { id: ID, name: NAME },
  });
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your code is fine, it will create a _and clause_ with passed fields in `where: { }`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you code should work, but you can try the following approach:

```js
const user = await Tags.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      { id: ID },
      { name: NAME }
    ]
  }
});
```

You can define operators for the where clause manually. For reference see https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#applying-where-clauses

Comment: I tried with that but i got an error, probably is something else that make that error

Answer (score 0):

here is an example . you have to user the Op from sequelize.

```
    const { Op } = require("sequelize");
    const isFoundNumber = await db.users.findOne({
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                mobile_number: params.mobile_number,
              },
              { email: params.email },
           

 ],
      },
    });

    if (isFoundNumber != null) {
      let user = basicDetails(isFoundNumber);
      if (params.mobile_number == user.mobile_number) {
        reject({
          status: false,
          errorMessage: `Mobile Number ${params.mobile_number} already regstered`,
          data: basicDetails(isFoundNumber),
        });
      }

      if (params.email === user.email) {
        reject({
          status: false,
          errorMessage: `Email Account ${params.email} already regstered`,
          data: user,
        });
      }
    }
```